# Question about specific step in proving Schur's Theorem (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, partial-fractions

I refer to p.98 of [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf) in proving [Schur's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Combinatorics):

The partial fraction expansion of $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is of the form

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H}(x) &= \frac{1}{(1-x^{a_1})(1-x^{a_2})\cdots(1-x^{a_M})} \\
&= \frac{c}{(1-x)^M} + O((1-x)^{-M+1})
\end{align*}

(where $a_1\le a_2\le \cdots\le a_M$ are M positive integers as defined earlier in the book.)

To calculate $c$, multiply both sides by $(1-x)^M$ and let $x\rightarrow 1$.  This gives $c=\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_M}$.

Question: can someone please help explain how multiplying both sides by $(1-x)^M$ and let $x\rightarrow 1$ would give $c=\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_M}$?  (I can see how the right hand side would reduce to $c$, but how does the left hand side reduce to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_M}$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hopital's Rule, $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac {1-x}{1-x^{a_k}}=\frac {1}{a_k}, \text{ so } \lim_{x \to 1} \prod_{k=1}^M \frac {1-x}{1-x^{a_k}}= \prod_{k=1}^M 
\frac{1}{a_k}.$$

Comment: So obvious in hindsight!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For each factor of $1-x^{a_i}$ in the denominator, we have
$$
\frac{1-x}{1-x^{a_i}} = \frac{1}{1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{a_i-1}}
$$
and as $x \to 1$, all $a_i$ of the terms in the denominator approach 1, so the overall fraction approaches $1/a_i$.  Applying this limit to each term in the product
$$
\frac{(1-x)^M}{\prod_{i=1}^M (1 - x^{a_i})} = \prod_{i=1}^M \frac{1-x}{1-x^{a_i}}
$$
then yields the desired result.

Comment: Make sense.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean to say that the overall fraction approaches $\frac{1}{a_i}$.

Comment: @RobertShore:  You're right, of course. Fixed.